# Reformat the string result from placemark

Tags: ios, nsstring, mkmapview, mapkit, mkplacemark

When i search a location sometimes i get this string from `placemark.subThoroughfare`
how can i reformat that sign to a normal "-"?

[image]

Best thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the problem is En Dash or Em Dash characters here is an example resolution. If your character is different look at the UTF8 data and use that instead.

```
NSString *enDashCharacter = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\xe2\x80\x93"];
NSString *emDashCharacter = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\xe2\x80\x94"];
NSLog(@"enDashCharacter: %@", enDashCharacter);
NSLog(@"emDashCharacter: %@", emDashCharacter);

NSString *textString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1-2 3%@4 5%@6", enDashCharacter,emDashCharacter];
NSData *textData = [textString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"textString: '%@'", textString);
NSLog(@"textData: %@", textData);

NSString *newString = textString;
newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:enDashCharacter withString:@"-"];
newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:emDashCharacter withString:@"-"];
NSLog(@"newString:  '%@'", newString);

NSData *newStringData = [newString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"newStringData: %@", newStringData);
```

NSLog output:
enDashCharacter: –
emDashCharacter: —
textString: ' 1 - 2 3 – 4 5 — 6 '
textData: <2031202d 20322033 20e28093 20342035 20e28094 203620>
newString:  ' 1 - 2 3 - 4 5 - 6 '
newStringData: <2031202d 20322033 202d2034 2035202d 203620>